# Seeking Neo4J Cypher query for long but (nearly) unique paths

Tags: neo4j, cypher

We have a Neo4J database representing an evolutionary process with about 100K nodes and 200K relations. Nodes are individuals in generations, and edges represent parent-child relationships. The primary goal is to be able to take one or nodes of interest in the final generation, and explore their evolutionary history (roughly, "how did we get here?").

The "obvious" first query to find all their ancestors doesn't work because there are just too many possible ancestors and paths through that space:

```
match (a)-[:PARENT_OF*]->(c {is_interesting: true}) 
return distinct a;
```

So we've pre-processed the data so that some edges are marked as "special" such that *almost* every node has at most one "special" parent edge, although occasionally both parent edges are marked as "special". My hope, then, was that this query would (efficiently) generate the (nearly) unique path along "special" edges:

```
match (a)-[r:PARENT_OF* {special: true}]->(c {is_interesting: true}) 
return distinct a;
```

This, however, is still unworkably slow.

This is frustrating because "as a human", the logic is simple: Start from the small number of "interesting" nodes (often 1, never more than a few dozen), and chase back along the almost always unique "special" edges. Assuming a very low number of nodes with two "special" parents, this should be something like O(N) where N is the number of generations back in time.

In Neo4J, however, going back 25 steps from a unique "interesting" node where *every* step is unique, however, takes 30 seconds, and once there's a *single* bifurcation (where both parents are "special") it gets worse much faster as a function of steps. 28 steps (which gets us to the first bifurcation) takes 2 minutes, 30 (where there's still only the one bifurcation) takes 6 minutes, and I haven't even thought to try the full 100 steps to the beginning of the simulation.

Some similar work last year seemed to perform better, but we used a variety of edge labels (e.g., `(a)-[:SPECIAL_PARENT_OF*]->(c)` as well as `(a)-[:PARENT_OF*]->(c)`) instead of using data fields on the edges. Is querying on relationship field values just not a good idea? We have quite a few different values attached to a relationship in this model (some boolean, some numeric) and we were hoping/assuming we could use those to efficiently limit searches, but maybe that wasn't really the case.

Suggestions for how to tune our model or queries would be greatly appreciated.

**Update** I should have mentioned, this is all with Neo4J 2.1.7. I'm going to give 2.2 a try as per Brian Underwood's suggestion and will report back.

Comment: I'd really like to see an answer to this myself.  I've definitely had some Cypher queries with open-ended path lengths which seemed like they shouldn't be traversing very much but which take a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After exploring things with the profiling tools in Neo4J 2.2 (thanks to Brian Underwood for the tip) it's pretty clear that (at the moment) Neo4J doesn't do any pre-filtering on edge properties, which leads to nasty combinatorial explosions with long paths.

For example the original query:

```
match (a)-[r:PARENT_OF* {special: true}]->(c {is_interesting: true}) 
return distinct a;
```

finds *all* the paths from `a` to `c` and *then* eliminates the ones that have edges that aren't `special`. Since there are many millions of paths from `a` to `c`, this is totally infeasible.

If I instead add a `IS_SPECIAL` edge wherever there was a `PARENT_OF` edge that had `{special: true}`, then the queries become really fast, allowing me to push back around 100 generations in under a second.

This query creates all the new edges:

```
match (a)-[r:PARENT_OF {special: true}]->(b) 
create (a)-[:IS_SPECIAL]->(b);
```

and takes under a second to add 91K relationships in our graph.

Then

```
match (c {is_interesting: true}) 
with c 
match (a)-[:IS_SPECIAL*]->(c) 
return distinct a;
```

takes under a second to find the 112 nodes along the "special" path back from a unique target node `c`. Matching `c` first and limiting the set of nodes using `with c` seems to also be important, as Neo4J doesn't appear to pre-filter on node properties either, and if there are several "interesting" target nodes things get a lot slower.

Answer (score 2):

I've had some luck with specifying a limit on the path length.  So if you know that it's never more than 30 hops you might try:

```
MATCH (c {is_interesting: true})
WITH c
MATCH (a)-[:PARENT_OF*1..30]->c 
RETURN DISTINCT a
```

Also, is there an index on the `is_interesting` property?  That could also cause slowness, for sure.

What version of Neo4j are you using?  If you are using or if you upgrade to 2.2.0, you get to use the new query profiling tools:

http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.0/how-do-i-profile-a-query.html

Also if you use them in the web console you get a nice graph-ish tree thing (technical term) showing each step.

Comment: We definitely would like to have long paths. We've been doing short paths as a workaround, but one definite goal is to be able to push all the way back to the beginning of the simulation.

I think there is an index on the `is_interesting` property. Running `schema ls` lists it, at least.

We are using 2.1.7 (sorry for not listing the version), but I'm definitely going to try 2.2 and see if that helps the situation, or if the profiling tools might help clarify what's going on.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Switching to 2.2 didn't improve the performance, but the profiling tools did help make it clear what the problem is. It is generating the full set of paths _without_ using the `is_interesting` property, and _then_ filtering with the `is_interesting` property. That initial set of paths quickly becomes huge, so the queries take forever. I'm guessing that if we had a special edge with `IS_INTERESTING` as its label, then it would be able to use that in pre-filtering the list of paths, thus speeding things up quite a bit.

Comment: Maybe also use a WITH clause to filter first?

Comment: I like the idea, but I'm not sure how to apply it. I know how to use a `WITH` to limit searching on _nodes_, but I'm not sure how to use it to limit searching on _edges_. Is there some way I can use `WITH` to say "only search paths with edges that have `is_interesting=true`?

Comment: Well I was thinking about searching on nodes first.  So you can see in my edit I filter out just nodes with `has_interesting` and then search for paths.  If you're looking for relationships with that property you can't do that, but I thought node properties was your first use case

Comment: Also, your example doesn't use labels, so important note: Indexes don't work without a label.  You put the index on a label and then you have to query for both the label and the property at the same time to take advantage of the index

Comment: The `is_interesting` property definitely needs to be on an edge rather than the nodes. A parent node might have an "interesting" relationship with one child, but not with another.

We do have labels on the nodes; I left them out to simplify the example some.

I found that adding new edges with an `IS_INTERESTING` label totally solves the problem. The query that added the new edges is really fast (much faster than I expected), and then I can query back across 100 generations in under a second.

Comment: In writing up a proposed answer below, I realized that I'd muddled up "interesting" and "special" here in the comments – sorry. I introduced those to replace the more complicated "real" properties in our domain, and started to use `is_interesting` to refer to edges when I should have been using `special`. So whenever I'm talking about relationships, they can be `special` or not, and it's nodes that can be `interesting` or node. I can't edit the older comments, so hopefully this helps.